# Objective C++, SIGABRT signal

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

Im doing an iOS app(actually just copying code) from this tutorial `http://hubpages.com/hub/Tutorial-on-Creating-an-IOS-5-SQLite-Database-Application-IOS-5-SQLite`
and I can't run my app. Build succeds and then I get signal `SIGABRT` in my XCode.

`2014-08-28 09:04:40.105 Whine2[526:60b] Problem with prepare statement
2014-08-28 09:04:40.109 Whine2[526:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x018d81e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016578e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x018793f6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
    3   Whine2                              0x000029bd -[kcbViewController viewDidLoad] + 269
    4   UIKit                               0x0043633d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    5   UIKit                               0x004365d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    6   UIKit                               0x00356267 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    7   UIKit                               0x003565ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    8   UIKit                               0x0035686b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    9   UIKit                               0x003613c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    10  UIKit                               0x00311bc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
    11  UIKit                               0x00316667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    12  UIKit                               0x0032af92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    13  UIKit                               0x0032b555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    14  UIKit                               0x00318250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x038cdf02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x038cda0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01853ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x018539db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0187e68c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0187d9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0187d7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  UIKit                               0x00315d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    23  UIKit                               0x00317f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  Whine2                              0x0000282d main + 141
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e21701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

I understand there is some problem with array, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error message and code in the link says, there is one array named `wines` in `viewDidLoad` of `kcbViewController` and it is empty. aJust log the array `wines` before accessing it . If you need to check whether an array is empty, you can check if `self.wines.count` is 0.